# R: Seq generation from sequences using vector points and for loops

Tags: r, seq

Looking to create a sequence of integers using values from vectors, seq = (x1:y1, x2:y2, x3:y3...xn:yn) where (x1 < y1 < x2 < y2 ... xn < yn). It gets difficult as n is random but always takes integer values.

I've tried creating a conditional if statement, and a for loop, both resulting in....nothing.

```
x <- c(1, 10, 26, 40)
y <- c(5, 13, 30, 51)
```

Normally, I'd suffice with

```
seqq <- c(seq(x1,y1,1),seq(x2,y2,1)...)
```

But the difficulty arises when n is of (more or less) random length. Trying to use a for loop i.e.

```
seqq <- c()

for (i in 1:length(x)){
    seqq[i] <- seq(x[i], y[i],1)  #I know this would technically create a vector of sequences
  i <- i+1
}

#results in
Error in seq.default(x[i], y[i], 1) : 'from' must be a finite number
```

to clarify im looking for

```
seqq <- c(1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,26,27,28,29,30,40,...,51)
```

Similarly, and if/while statement doesn't actually do anything
Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` to get the sequence between corresponding elements of 'x' and 'y' and then `unlist` the `list` of `vector`s

```
unlist(Map(`:`, x, y))
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5 10 11 12 13 26 27 28 29 30 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51
```

---

A similar option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(x, y, `:`) %>% 
       flatten_int
```

NOTE: We can also change the `:` with `seq` and should work as well. By default, the `by` is 1.  That would be more general in case if we need to generate sequence with different `by`

---

Regarding the OP's issue with `for` loop, the `seqq` is defined as a `NULL` vector.  So, if we do the `seqq[i]`, there is no element to index.  In this case, it would be better to concatenate (`c`) in each iteration and assign it to 'seqq', so the vector grows in size appending the values of each iteration at the end

```
for(i in seq_along(x)) seqq <- c(seqq, seq(x[i], y[i]))
```

Comment: that was easy, thanks!